# execution reverted: uniswapv2library: insufficient_input_amount when using swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I am facing the error, execution reverted: uniswapv2library: insufficient_input_amount when using swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens.

The tokenAmount is 18 decimals. (8072364872364293879238745)
There is enough liquidity in the pool and i have swapped this exact amount using the uniswap app with no problems, multiple times.

```
function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0,
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, so i assume you have another problem that the tokenAmount you are passing to the contract is zero.

The only time this error occurs is when the input is zero.
https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/dda62473e2da448bc9cb8f4514dadda4aeede5f4/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol